# Ember computed property from array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to include a computed flag in my model when a particular string exists in an included array.

```
userType: DS.attr(),   // ['Don','Ben','Dec', 'Con']

isDon: Ember.computed('userType', function() {
return (!((this.get('userType')).includes('Don'));
 }).property('userType'),
```

any help ?

Comment: the `.property()` makes me wonder if you are looking at old docs. What version are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. It looks you are mixing the two different way of defining computed properties,

```
isDon: Ember.computed('userType', function() {
  return (!((this.get('userType')).includes('Don'));
 }),
```

If you want to recalculate `isDon` every when you add/remove elements from `userType` then consider the dependant key as `userType.[]`

Refer
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/object-model/computed-properties/
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/#toc_code-code-vs-code-each-code

Answer (score 0):

for some strange reason, userType was not treated as an array so I had to create a computed property like

```
userRoles: Ember.computed('userType.[]', function () {
return Ember.A(this.get('userType'));
}),
isDon: Ember.computed('userRoles', function () {
return this.get('userRoles').filter((item) => item == 'Don').length > 0;
}),
```